# How to start bumblebee daemon on boot?

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, bumblebee

I've followed this guide https://askubuntu.com/questions/549915/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-with-bumblebee-on-ubuntu-14-04/549916#549916?newreg=d84c5f76c60549288d9d3937d32ca753

Bumblebee works just fine, except that every time I reboot I i will end up in blank screen ie no display then i have to force shut down my laptop by pressing the power key for few mins 
and power on it again now display works
 And now if i run optirun glxspheres64 i get this

```
sooorajjj@Treako ~ $ optirun glxspheres64
[  226.447578] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[  226.447636] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

then i have to manually restart `bumblebeed` and now `optirun` works

```
sooorajjj@Treako ~ $ sudo service bumblebeed restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
bumblebeed start/running, process 2772
sooorajjj@Treako ~ $ optirun glxspheres64
Polygons in scene: 62464 (61 spheres * 1024 polys/spheres)
Visual ID of window: 0x20
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 740M/PCIe/SSE2
113.118247 frames/sec - 100.430904 Mpixels/sec
114.656793 frames/sec - 101.796887 Mpixels/sec
```

Iam using lenovo z500 - linux mint 17.2

> Nvidia driver i use

```
sooorajjj@Treako ~ $ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  bumblebee-nvidia                            3.2.1-93~trustyppa1                                    amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support using the proprietary NVIDIA driver
ii  nvidia-346-updates                          346.96-0ubuntu0.0.1                                    amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 346.96
ii  nvidia-settings                             346.72-0ubuntu1                                        amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

> so there is 2 questions 
>   1) how to enable bumblebeed at every boot 
>   2) Whats causing normal reboot to go to blank screen  ( how could i debug
>   this , is this anything related to 1st question ? )

Comment: Can you please check if there is a init.d script? `ls -la /etc/init.d/bumblebeed`

Comment: Hi @lese , here is output
'sooorajjj@Treako ~ $ ls -la /etc/init.d/bumblebeed 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4542 Jan 18  2014 /etc/init.d/bumblebeed'

Comment: Oh I just saw it, you are using linux mint with GUI, it is easy to add a service to start on boot, see my reply about that, but I'm not sure it will fix your problem with Graphic card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using linux mint 17.2 too:

```
# cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.2
DISTRIB_CODENAME=rafaela
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
cat: /etc/upstream-release: Is a directory
```

There is an application installed by default called "Startup Applications", start it and try to add the following entry :

[image]

Then reboot and lets see what happen : )

Comment: it still goes to blank screen (ie when i restart ) also`sooorajjj@Treako ~ $ optirun glxspheres64
[   79.946371] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[   79.946487] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?`

Comment: also bumblebeed service doesnt start on boot
`sooorajjj@Treako ~ $ sudo /usr/sbin/bumblebeed --daemon
[sudo] password for sooorajjj: 
sooorajjj@Treako ~ $ optirun glxspheres64
Polygons in scene: 62464 (61 spheres * 1024 polys/spheres)
ERROR in line 630:
Could not obtain RGB visual with requested properties`

Comment: I would try to run the following command : `sudo update-rc.d bumblebeed defaults`

Comment: ie i added i have added it to startup application but no success

Comment: probably first try didn't work because Startup Application program is executed with your normal user "sooorajjj" which does not have permission to execute /etc/init.d/bumblebeed

Comment: if you run, from the command line, `sudo update-rc.d bumblebeed defaults` you should workaround this "problem"

Comment: but it sill wont solve the restart issue i have blank screen on restart , also no since i use `sudo update-rc.d bumblebeed defaults` should i remove bumblebleed from start up applications

Comment: Yes you should remove bumblebleed entry from  Startup Application. The command `sudo update-rc.d bumblebeed defaults` do its job.

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to help you about Graphic Card driver problem. I thought it was related to bumblebleed not starting on boot. But definitively it's not. Good luck man

Answer (score -1):

Type the command as follows.

```
sudo systemctl enable bumblebeed ; reboot
```

This works well on my debian linux.

Comment: OP already got the issue with startup of `bumblebeed` fixed two years ago, if you read the comments under the previous answer, so this doesn't resolve the blank screen issue he was left with (although that isn't mentioned in the question title).